# Regular Expression in .net

Tags: .net, regex

1. strSearch contains (all letters) and
   (no spaces)
2. strSearch contains (all letters) and
   (has ONE space)
3. strSearch contains (all letters) and
   (a comma)
4. strSearch contains (all letters) and
   (a *)

how can I write regular expression for these. As I am new to regular expression.

Comment: Since you're new to regular expressions, I'll recommend learning regular expressions. A good place to start is here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: I would check http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm also, here you can test regex and a breakdown in english what it's matching for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pointers:

`\p{L}` is a shortcut for "any letter".

`^` and `$` anchor the regex at the start and end of the string, making sure the entire string is matched.

`*` means "zero or more of the preceding item".

`\*` means a literal `*`.

So now you can construct your regex.

Number 1 (as a C# string): `@"^\p{L}*$"`.

Number 2: `@"^\p{L}* \p{L}*$"`

I think you can take it from here...

Comment: +1 because I need not to finish my answer, that would have been going in the same direction.